# DBIx::Class::ResultSet problems

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I've got the following code:

```
package MyPackage::ResultSet::Case;
use base 'DBIx::Class::ResultSet';

sub cases_last_fourteen_days {
    my ($self, $username) = @_; 

    return $self->search({
                username    => $username,
                date        => { '>=' => 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)' },
    }); 
};
```

But when I try to use it this way:

```
$schema->resultset('Case')->cases_last_fourteen_days($username)
```

I always get zero results, can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you use the SQL::Abstract condition would result in this where condition:

```
WHERE username = ? AND date >= 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)'
```

When you wish to use database functions in a where clause you need to use [a reference to a scalar](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.71/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Literal_SQL), like this:

```
date        => { '>=' => \'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)' },
```

**ProTip**: if you set the environment variable `DBIC_TRACE` to 1, DBIx::Class will print the queries it generates to STDERR ... this way you can check if it really does what you wish.

Comment: For resultset it is possible to append `->as_query` which will return resulting query